# Simulating Raw mouse input through chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, ui-automation

I am developing a chrome extension to fill up some forms automatically. Problem is, these websites are using React.js and other Javascript components that make adding input or selecting from autocomplete menus very difficult.
Now I am aware that the chrome.debugger API for chrome extensions allow for this, but I just cannot seem to get it work.
Could someone guide me as to how I can use this API to click on elements, and sending keyboard input?

Comment: You should send one of these [Input](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Input/) commands. However usually a normal DOM dispatchEvent is sufficient if you send all the events that the site listens to. You can see them in devtools, the event listeners panel.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for the reply. I have tried dispatchEvent with mixed success. Some elements I can interact with, others completely refuse to budge.
For example, I focus on a certain input field, type a string in it, and an autocomplete dropdown appears with the string. Now, I want to click on the item in the dropdown to confirm the string I typed, but I am unable to do so with dispatchEvent.
The Input commands you linked to seem like would work. However, I do not know how to use them. Could you kindly give me an example of a "Input.dispatchMouseEvent" so I can understand how it works?

Comment: for keyboard simulation, you can use keypress or SimulateWordTyping from here- https://github.com/fxnoob/speech-recognition-toolkit/blob/master/src/services/dom.js

Comment: RE Autocomplete. All implementations are different but in my experience you need to first add text to the field. Then you need to wait till the HTML updates with the autocomplete selection. Once the new HTML is there you need to check the choices and click on the element that you want. I set up an observer before typing and then the observer handles the waiting until the autocomplete shows up.

Comment: @darbid I can get the autocomplete to show up. I'm just having trouble clicking on the option that comes up.

Comment: In my experience the user interface that appears is a whole new HTML element sometimes added at the bottom of the tree. You need to open Chrome developer and view the element tree while typing to see what appears.

Comment: @darbid I can see the new element in the html tree. I just cannot seem to click on it, or select it through JS.

Comment: What’s the URL, is it public?

Comment: @darbid www.grailed.com. when you click on sell, and select the option to create new item, you get a form to fill out. In the "brand" field, once you enter a brand name (let's say adidas) you are presented with that option in a dropdown  autocomplete menu. I am having trouble selecting that option from the menu.

Comment: When I click on sell I don’t see create new item, I see Details with 4 text fields, category, item name, designer and size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will guess that the designer field works the same way.  When you add text to that field then a child UL is added to this div element.

```
   <div class="designer-autocomplete-container input-with-error">
       <input id="designer-autocomplete" class="" type="text" placeholder="Designer" autocomplete="off" value="">
   </div>
```

Here below is a screen shot of the UL and LI elements that are added.  This is your dropdown.
[image: screen shot]

Then you are right you cannot call the click(); function on the LI elements, you need to do this;

```
var clickEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
clickEvent.initEvent('mousedown', true, true);
document.querySelector("#sellform > div > div.sellform-form-wrapper > form > div.details-container.section > div > div.left-column > div.designers-input > div:nth-child(1) > ul > li:nth-child(6)").dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
```

I simply used the Chrome developer to Copy JS Path to get the LI element. You could/will def make this nicer by looping through the choices and checking the innertext for the value you want to then click on.  By the way be careful using the ID=designer-autocomplete they use this for the input element more than once.

Comment: I have tried this but it doesn't work for me. Did you test this out? This is why I am looking for a solution that involves raw mouse input.

Comment: Sure did. I wrote and tested it as pictured in the developer console. I would suggest you do the same so you know it works. My guess is you are not waiting long enough for the LI element to be ready. This is step 2.

Comment: You are right. It's working in console. I'll check why it isnt working in my extension. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ok. I added a settimeout of 5000ms and it worked. I'll try to make my code more efficient so as to listen for when changes are made to the element instead of a discrete timeout. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: set up a MutationObserver https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver before you start typing and watch for the LI to come in, once you get the one you want then fire my text above.